# Algorithm behind javascript CCV library

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a face detection application using phonegap and javascript CCV face detection library. I need to know name of the algorithm behind the CCV face detection library for further developments.

Comment: https://github.com/liuliu/ccv could this help?